# SVN - Deleted lines of code

Tags: tortoisesvn

How to find the deleted lines of code between two date range in SVN. I am using Tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the diff command to do so and grep in the output the "-" sign which is indicating a line has been deleted.

```
svn diff -rRange URL1 URL2
```

Comment: For modification of line, svn will make it as one deleted line and one added line. This will not give actual deleted lines.

Comment: for 'Range' you can use something like `{20130617T1530}:348494`. You don't need the urls if execute from a working copy

Answer (score 0):

You want to ["diff" between two files](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html).

To find the dates, you can [look at the revision logs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).